# Switching a Circuit on-and-off In-step with the Rotation of a Drive-shaft (Mechanically)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, design, circuits, prototyping

I'm working on a project. The Salient part here is a drive-shaft connected to a bearing, onto which a simple circuit is mounted. I want to switch the circuit on every $π$ and off for the other $π$ of a full $2π$. In other words, I want it on for every half rotation. I want to do this mechanically because non-mechanical solution seem like they might be **hard to sync**. Also, the solution needs to interfere with the machine's operation as little as possible. **It is a complex machine that will be subjected to high moisture and so forth, so ideally, the switching system would entirely co-rotate with the shaft.**

I don't know if there are any 'ready made solutions,' or not, but i'd be thankful to be pointed in the right direction (towards something plausible), or told I should wing it and create something from scratch (presumably because there isn't any solution that can simply be bought at a hardware shop).

thanks.

Comment: Does your simple circuit have have a micro-controller. A micro-controller will solve your problem.

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena Thanks for the answer, but I would think that would have issues because the thing involves variable RPM.

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena In addition, I'd rather not complicate things too much with sensors, ETC...

Comment: 2 magnets, a sensor and a relay that stays on until the next pulse.

Comment: How fast is it spinning?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift The max speed if 5000 RPM. Thank you!

Comment: I did not ask for the speed. I gave you a suggestion as you asked.

Comment: Thank you, sorry, I tagged the wrong person. @SolarMike

Comment: Is this battery powered? You can centrifuge the electrolyte out of the battery.

Comment: @DDuck, yes, it's battery powered (the circuit) but I'm unsure of what you mean by "You can centrifuge the electrolyte out of the battery."

Comment: A battery with no electrolyte doesn't work.  A battery in the rotor can fail because the electrolyte has been removed by centrifugal action.  It might not cause the battery to completely fail but may change it's internal resistance  - so it may be unable to deliver the required power

Comment: Why not use sliding contacts like on the commutator of a brushed DC motor?

Answer (score 2):

Without a sketch your setup is difficult to visualise. A typical industrial solution would be to use an inductive proximity switch. These are non-contact, fast switching, water-proof, etc.

[image]

*Figure 1. A selection of inductive proximity switches.*

You seem to suggest that the switch and circuit will rotate. This means that you need to consider those forces applied to the sensor and any rotor imbalance that the switch may cause.